# allow input with decimal places upto 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow only integers and floats (upto 3 decimal places) in a text box, how can I achieve this using javascript?

**Valid** values are

```
1234
12.3
12.314
1.11
0.4
```

**Not valid**

```
1.23456
abcd or any other character
```

Comment: Are you already using a JavaScript validation framework?

Comment: Is `.1` and `1.` valid?

Comment: @coure2011 Because I like explicit answers, are you saying that `.1` **is** valid? And what about an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment that you need to also match `".1"` you need to add a conditional with the first part of the regular expression.

```
var re = /^(\d+)?(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/;
```

[Rough test suite - jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNZAx/2/)

Comment: How to allow `%` in last? e.g. 14.54%

Comment: Add it before the dollar sign.

Comment: I used `/^(\d+)?(?:\.\d{1,3})?%{1}?$/` and it seems to work. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to do this:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/
```

That's the start of the string (`^`), one or more digits (`\d+`), optionally followed by a `.` and between 1 and 3 digits (`(?:\.\d{1,3})`), then the end of the string (`$`).

To compare it to the value of an input, you'd do something like this:

```
var re = /^\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/;
var testValue = document.getElementById('id-of-input').value;
if(re.test(testValue)) {
    // matches - input is valid
}
else {
    // doesn't match - input is invalid
}
```

Take a look at [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/37eh7/).

Comment: @epascarello I'll update when they explicitly confirm that `.1` is valid input; until then I'd consider it invalid.

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression to validate your input field , regular rexpression is as below

```
^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

Comment: Your reg exp fails a lot of tests. You are missing a +. You can see [tests here](http://jsfiddle.net/2cawf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var reg=/^[\d]+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/;
str=10.2305;
str1=123;
alert(reg.test(str));
alert(reg.test(str1));
```

Check **Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8mURL/1

Comment: @epascarello Test the above I have changed.